# Very new to PS - different results when running commands vs .ps1

Tags: powershell

trying to get some basic stuff scripted. When I run some commands in a powershell window I get a nice simple list however if I run a .ps1 file with the same command I get an unnecessarily verbose output. Is there a "less verbose" flag or setting I'm not aware of?

while this issue in particular is likely not tied to the commands I'm using, for reference I am using this command in this instance:

`invoke-command -computername $servers -scriptblock {Get-Package -Name PSWindowsUpdate}`

EDIT: For future readers - I solved the issue by inserting Select-Object Name as well. This provides a concise list:

`invoke-command -computername $servers -scriptblock {get-package -name pswindowsupdate | select-object name}`

Comment: Judging by the solution you edited into your question (which is generally best avoided - post an _answer_ instead), you've presented a red herring in your question: It wasn't about script vs. no-script invocation, but about _direct invocation_ vs. _invocation via remoting_ (`Invoke-Command -ComputerName ...`). Therefore, I suggest (a) fixing your question to state the real problem and removing the later edit from your question. and (b) accepting js2010's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't format the same over invoke-command. It's a serialized object now, so the type is different.  I usually do

`icm $comps { get-package program | select name,version }`

You won't even see the output of select-string without extra help:

```
icm $comps { echo hi | select-string hi | select line }
```

Those without multiple computers can try invoke-command with localhost at the elevated powershell prompt.  All the object properties get dumped because the object's serialized.

```
invoke-command localhost { get-package 'google chrome' }


PropertyOfSoftwareIdentity : PropertyOfSoftwareIdentity
PSComputerName             : localhost
RunspaceId                 : d843e737-577c-4d04-be21-7ab608694c79
FastPackageReference       : {E9AB118B-2341-3DD2-BD45-27B55F5F3802}
ProviderName               : msi
Source                     :
Status                     : Installed
SearchKey                  : google chrome
FullPath                   :
PackageFilename            : ?
FromTrustedSource          : False
Summary                    :
SwidTags                   : {Microsoft.PackageManagement.Packaging.SoftwareIdentity}
CanonicalId                : msi:Google Chrome/108.0.5359.99
Metadata                   : {ProductCode}
SwidTagText                : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
                             <SoftwareIdentity
                               name="Google Chrome"
                               version="108.0.5359.99"
                               versionScheme="multipartnumeric"
                               tagId="E9AB118B-2341-3DD2-BD45-27B55F5F3802"
                             xmlns="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19770/-2/2015/schema.xsd">
                               <Meta
                                 ProductCode="{E9AB118B-2341-3DD2-BD45-27B55F5F3802}" />
                             </SoftwareIdentity>
Dependencies               : {}
IsCorpus                   :
Name                       : Google Chrome
Version                    : 108.0.5359.99
VersionScheme              : multipartnumeric
TagVersion                 :
TagId                      : E9AB118B-2341-3DD2-BD45-27B55F5F3802
IsPatch                    :
IsSupplemental             :
AppliesToMedia             :
Meta                       : {{ProductCode}}
Links                      : {}
Entities                   : {}
Payload                    :
Evidence                   :
Culture                    :
Attributes                 : {name,version,versionScheme,tagId}
```